# How can I webscrape data from website without HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, web, dynamic

How do I go about web scraping data from a website below to find specific case details?

Here are the manual steps to find case details:

1. Navigate to https://www.claytoncountyga.gov/government/courts/court-case-inquiry/
2. There seems to be possibly a JavaScript-loaded form with buttons/inputs to take your further to case details - need to select Name Search to search for cases by Last Name - click it
3. Then a new screen appears within the same element of (2) allowing user to select from drop down court (eg, Magistrate Court) and free form text input to enter Last Name and First Name (Smith John).
4. Clicking submit takes you to all the cases
5. Clicking the case number on one of the rows in the table populated within the same  Element as all prior steps allows you to view case details - I’d like to scrape data from this page.

Because the inner form seems encapsulated (I’m guessing with Javascript), I can’t see the HTML elements that render after each input is provided. How can i automate this with Python?

Comment: there is an iframe there. you need to switch to it to interact with elements inside it. Provide what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is contained inside an `iframe` with ID "Clayton County". For selenium to be able to interact with elements inside it, we first have to switch to it using the `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` method.

Then using `Select()` we can select an option from the dropdown menu.

In the last page we grab all the case numbers urls and save them in `case_numbers_urls`, so that we can loop over them, load each one, grab info and pass to the next one.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path))
driver.get('https://www.claytoncountyga.gov/government/courts/court-case-inquiry/')

# page 1
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 9)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "Clayton County")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'Name Search')]").click()

# page 2
dropdown = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "ctt")))
Select(dropdown).select_by_value('M')
lname = 'Smith'
fname = 'John'
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'lname').send_keys(lname)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fname').send_keys(fname)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btnSrch').click()

# page 3
case_numbers_urls = [c.get_attribute('href') for c in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#myTable a[href]:not([rel])')))]
for url in case_numbers_urls:
    driver.get(url)
    # do something
```